# What does the @ symbol mean on filenames

Tags: ls

When I do an `ls` in the `/proc/PID` directory a number of @ symbols show up next to the file names.  Normally I would consider this to mean extended attributes but when I do the long form of `ls` they do not show up in the place I would expect and the output looks different than usual.  I tried googling but only found the extended attributes description.  What is going on?

```
root@hashcat:/proc/29286/ns# l
ipc@  mnt@  net@  pid@  user@  uts@
root@hashcat:/proc/29286/ns#
root@hashcat:/proc/29286/ns# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dylan dylan 0 Mar 21 21:09 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dylan dylan 0 Mar 21 21:09 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dylan dylan 0 Mar 21 21:09 net -> net:[4026531956]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dylan dylan 0 Mar 21 21:09 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dylan dylan 0 Mar 21 21:09 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dylan dylan 0 Mar 21 21:09 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

Comment: You don't do an `ls` but an `l` which is likely an alias of `ls -F`.

Comment: So it indicated that it is a symbolic link and `ls -l` is showing what the links are pointing to. Thanks

Comment: I really hope you "tried googling" as "tired goggling" seldom makes you see anything new.

Comment: Apparently I WAS tired googling!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per default `ls` does not print those classifiers. Most probably you are using an alias referring to `ls -F`. (You can use `type ls` or `type l` to check.)

The `-F` option is documented in `info ls`:

```
‘-F’
‘--classify’
‘--indicator-style=classify’
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’.  The file
     type indicators are ‘/’ for directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links,
     ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets, ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.  Do not follow symbolic links listed on the command
     line unless the ‘--dereference-command-line’ (‘-H’),
     ‘--dereference’ (‘-L’), or
     ‘--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir’ options are specified.
```

Therefore the entries with a `@` are symlinks. Actually a symlink stores only an arbitrary string, that usually is the name of another file, but in your case the kernel just inserts a description containing an internal id.

Comment: Great thanks! I should have looked into what `l` was an alias for and go from there.  I get so dumb sometimes, sometimes by brain just won't work through something... Prob doesn't help I have been at it all day.  Thank you again!

Comment: and what does the * symbol mean in the same context?

Comment: See the quoted documentation above: executable

Comment: Good Explain ...